# Why is the big o of this function xn^2?

Tags: big-o

I have the following function:

```
public String joinWords(String[] words) {
  String sentence = "";
  for(String w : words) {
    sentence = sentence + w;
  }
}
```

I am told this is a O(n^2)? Why is that? Is it not O(n) for having one loop?

Comment: If a new string is being created each time, copying the existing value of `sentence` into it takes O(n) time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop is, indeed, iterated `words.length` times.

However, on each iteration the old `sentence` string is discarded, and a new `sentence` string is created. In the process of creating the new `sentence` the previous one is copied into the new one, and then the `word` is appended. Each act of copying takes O(n), so overall loop takes O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 1):

Loops with string concatenation are weird. The compiler can convert the concatenations to stringBuilders but not in loops as such, though this should be well within the realm of compiler ability.

The typical java compiler converts your statement to:

```
public String joinWords(String[] words) {
  String sentence = "";
  for(String w : words) {
    sentence = new StringBuilder().append(sentence).append(w).toString()
  }
}
```

So each time it does this you still end up copying each digit to the new String.  Which is the source of the other loop.

You can obviously convert this to things like (in Android):

```
TextUtils.join("",words);
```

Or the String.join() command in Java8. And there's more than a few useful ways to do this with streams. But, due to the internals yeah, that loops going to be O(N^2).

Obviously:

```
public String joinWords(String[] words) {
      String sentence = "";
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for(String w : words) {
          sb.append(w);
      }
      return sb.toString();
}
```

Fixes it too.

The extra loop doesn't need to be there. But with string concatenation in a loop it is.